# Error when add Gdata to project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, gdata-api

I add Gdata to my project and set other C Flags:

```
Debug : -DDEBUG=1
Other Linker Flags : -lxml2 -ObjC
C Language Dialect:  C99 [-sd=c99]
```

But it show error in `GDataServiceBase`:

```
 "Duplicate interface declaration for class GMHTTPUploadFetcher".
```

What should I do to fix it ???

Comment: I am having the same problem. Anybody knows how to resolve it ?